# Why does an email signature image look blurry on iCloud Mail but for the exact same file, looks crisp on Outlook & Gmail?

Tags: icloud, email, ms-office, gmail, signature

For reference, I've created an email signature image saved as PNG, this file consists of a logo and some text, for which the logo was a vector (copied and pasted across from one .ai file to another .ai file, therefore resolution was not lost there) and font/text has been created as outlines as well.

This final email signature image was then saved (as mentioned above, in PNG) with a resolution of 300 ppi (I have also tried 72ppi and 150ppi) and also tried with double the size (in terms of dimensions) for the purpose of scaling down/resizing when in use.

When imported as a signature into the Outlook & Gmail settings, both appear crisp and clear regardless of the size and resolution, however, on iCloud Mail, it appears very blurry for the exact same file/resolution even at 'Actual Size'. I understand that there are limitations with actual dimension resizing on iCloud Mail, but would there be a workaround or a solution for this? Maybe in terms of how I should be creating or saving the file as my client's email is firmly hosted on iCloud Mail.

Thank you very much, sorry just running out of ideas and have tried researching to no avail.

Comment: how about other images from iCloud